# 'not everyone is prepared' : Is 'not' a determiner?

Tags: adverbs, determiners

> Despite the overnight detention of Thailand's ousted prime minister Yingluck Shinawatra and a number of family members and politicians, there are indications today that **not everyone is prepared** to obey the commands of the leaders of the military coup. ([Aussie ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4011299.htm))

When I read the bold part: *not everyone is prepared*, I wonder if I have to take *not* as a determiner for the next noun, *everyone*, just as in *half* of *half the season*. Or if *not* is preposed/shifted from *everyone is not prepared*. Which is it?

Comment: *Not* is a pre-head dependent in the NP *not everyone*, and it has scope over the quantifier *every-*, just as it would in "[not every] person".  It is a marker of non-verbal negation and doesn't modify *prepared*.  See CGEL p.424, 795, 807.

Comment: @snailplane, Thank you very much, yours is just what I wanted.

Comment: @snailplane O very handsome. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For readers who are not familiar with the technical language, or do not have access to the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language:

OP knows that when a noun phrase (NP) starts with a chain of modifiers, the first or only word in the chain is ordinarily a *determiner*: an article (such as *a*, *an*, *the*) or a demonstrative (such as *this*, *that*, *those* or a quantifier (such as a number or *some*, *all*, *every*, *few*) or a possessive (such as *his*, *her*, *John's*).

Seeing that the subject of the clause *not everybody is prepared to obey the commands &c* is the NP *not everybody*, she wonders whether *not* is to be understood as a determiner, or is the ordinary negator which has been moved to the front from its ordinary position in *Everyone is not prepared*.

Snailplane answers that this *not* is a special kind of modifier ("pre-head dependent") which precedes *everyone* in order to negate only that constituent, not the entire sentence. *Not everyone is prepared* means *[not every] one is prepared*—some people *may* be prepared, but at least one person is not.

This is the ordinary way in which we partially deny an assertion about *everyone*, *everybody*, *all (of)*, *everything*, *one*, or about NPs in which these are used in the possessive

> Not everything you read on the internet is true.
>   Not all of us agree with you.
>   Not one of us agrees with you.
>   Not everybody's mother is so forgiving as his.

*Not* can also be used this way with some other quantifiers/quantified pronouns, such *not many*, *not a few*, *not much*, *not a little*.

> Not many were impressed with his lecture.
>   Not a few of us think otherwise.

But these expressions are only used at the beginning of a **subject** NP. For instance, we do not say

> <sup>∗</sup> He greeted not everyone.
>   <sup>∗</sup> He gave not everyone a smile.

*Not* is not used this way with other quantifiers/quantified pronouns except in *not..but* constructions; these constructions can play any syntactic role:

> Not some but all of us are angry.
>   They gave not three but eight scholarships.

Comment: These are all the rules I can come up with off the top of my head; if any reader knows more, or can point to authoritative online treatments, please feel free to add them to this.