# Difference between Determiners and Noun Modifiers

Tags: nouns, determiners, modifiers

**Hello.**

I would like to know whether or not there is a reasonable explanation for why both grammatical classes use different terminologies.

Both **Determiners** and **Noun Modifiers**  perform exactly the same function: *Modify nouns, and nothing more*. So, why has it been termed differently as well as their placement:

> **Determiners:**
>
> Pre-determiners
>
> Central-determiners
>
> Post-determiners
>
> **Modifiers:**
>
> Pre-modifiers
>
> Post-Modifiers

There is already a [topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40232/whats-the-difference-between-modifiers-and-determiners) that discusses the same thing; however, the answers weren't clear enough to me, also, there was only one answer, and I want to go deep into this topic.

Comment: Determiners don't modify. Their function is to mark a noun as definite or indefinite.

Comment: @BillJ - I'm sure that Determiners have many other functions, such as quantifying and numering; however, it's a discussion for another trend. Do you have any opinion regarding such a topic?

Comment: It depends to some degree on what theoretical framework you are using. But typically, determiners are more restricted, you can use only one (or maybe, only one of each type) in a noun phrase, whereas you can use arbitrarily many modifiers.

Comment: @Colin - Yeah, that pretty much makes sense; whereas Determiners are limited and must be placed correctly, Noun Modifiers are ilimited and can be placed in any position. Thank you, that is the answer that I am more likely to get since it is the only difference I have found so far.